# Casting from Java primitive int to double

Tags: java, types, casting

If I call

```
methodName(5, 1/2);
```

and it has the signature

```
public static int methodName(int x, double y){
}
```

does the `methodName` receive `y` with a value of `0` or `0.5`?

Comment: Why just don't try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int y = 1/2;`

At this point, y is 0. If you try to cast it to a double afterwards it will be 0.0. It doesn't remember how it got its value, just what its value is.

EDIT: I think the compiler will actually replace `1/2` with 0 at compile time. Making the code literally identical to `int y = 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
int y = 1/2;
```

In this code, y will be 0;

If you want to get it as 0.5

Have a try with the following code:

```
double y = 1.0 * 1 /2; //y is 0.5
```

Comment: Why `1.0 * 1 / 2` when you can do `1.0 / 2`?

Comment: This is just an example to indicate that we can not use 1/2 to get 0.5. We need to convert one of the int value into double value. 1.0/2 or 1/2.0

Answer (score 0):

It will evaluate to 0.

There's not a whole lot you can do with the above code.

There should be no specific reason to store y as an int.

Try this instead:

```
double y = 1/2.0;
```

Comment: im having an exam today, just in case this situation shows up ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
int y = 1/2
```

Since you're using 1 (int) and 2 (int) to make the division, it's an integer division, thus `y = 0` (and remainder (%) is 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with parameters (the parenthesis). In java every method has a set of parameters (they might not hold values ex: exampleMethod()).

A parameter is a variable that is passed into the method, so when in your code you call:

```
methodName() initialize it with methodName(x,y);
```

the x and y inside the method are just pointers for the values you pass through the parameters. I would suggest that you name your variables differently to avoid this confusion. For example:

```
int x;
int y;
methodName(int argX, double argY)
{

}
```

Also to answer your question, an int cuts off its stored value at the decimal point, so 5.9 would round to 5 rather than 6, so if you needed a floating point variable for y, either declare it as a float or a double, either will work, but most methods in the java library are written to take doubles as parameters rather than floats